# SQL Server: Transpose rows to columns redux

Tags: t-sql, unpivot, entity-attribute-value

I've been reading all of the transpose rows to columns links on the whole of Stack, but I can't quite get the code in those to work with my situation.

I have a device table
    deviceID
    DeviceName

I have an attribute table
    AttributeID
    AttributeName

and then I have a many to many mapping table of devices to attributes
    DeviceId
    AttributeID
    AttributeValue

so let's say one of the attributes is the device's name and another is its IP address.  When I make a query joining these 3 tables I'll get 2 rows for a given device

deviceID    attributeName    attributeValue
2                name                    Server1
2                IPAddress            10.1.1.1

What I need is a view that flattens it back out so I have an output that looks like this:
deviceid    name        IPAddress
2                Server1    10.1.1.1

Sample Code please - I just was not able to get an unpivot to work

Thank you,

Comment: What you describe is a well known *problem*, the dreaded Entity-Attribute-Value table. It doesn't offer any flexibility but it *does* cause a lot of problems and makes querying impossible. You can have up to 32000 sparse columns in a table. You can store data in XML or JSON columns. In fact, sparse columns use XML for storage of only the fields with actual values

Comment: The best option is to redesign the table and either use sparse columns or JSON. To get table-like results from this you'd need *PIVOT* and specifying all the "attribute names" both in the `FOR` and column list. You'd have to use aggregate functions like `MIN` on every column to reduce the possibly multiple values to a single one. Right now you have no way to specify the type of the "attributes", specify constraints or indexes.

Comment: Ok, that makes perfect sense.  I will change the database design.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #device
(
    deviceID   INT           NOT NULL
  , DeviceName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #attribute
(
    AttributeID   INT           NOT NULL
  , AttributeName NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE #bridgeDeviceAttribute
(
    DeviceId       INT           NOT NULL
  , AttributeID    INT           NOT NULL
  , AttributeValue NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #device (deviceID, DeviceName) VALUES (2, N'MyDevice');

INSERT INTO #attribute
    (
        AttributeID
      , AttributeName
    )
VALUES
    (1, N'name')
  , (2, N'IPAddress');

INSERT INTO #bridgeDeviceAttribute
    (
        DeviceId
      , AttributeID
      , AttributeValue
    )
VALUES
    (2, 1, N'Server1')
  , (2, 2, N'10.1.1.1');

SELECT
     pvt.deviceID
   , pvt.name
   , pvt.IPAddress
FROM (
         SELECT
              d.deviceID
            , a.AttributeName
            , bda.AttributeValue
         FROM #bridgeDeviceAttribute bda
              JOIN #attribute        a
                ON a.AttributeID = bda.AttributeID
              JOIN #device           d
                ON d.deviceID = bda.DeviceId
     ) t
PIVOT (
          MIN(AttributeValue)
          FOR AttributeName IN (name, IPAddress)
      ) pvt;
```

Results look like this:

[image]